# So strange result of wp_query and have_posts

Tags: wp-query

I've tested some piece of simple code, but the result is so so strange.

**Test 1:**

```
$featured_posts = new WP_Query( $query_args );
while ($featured_posts->have_posts()) {
    $featured_posts->the_post();
    the_title(); echo '<br>';           
}
echo 'End: "' . $featured_posts->have_posts() . '"'; // have_post() is TRUE, WHY?
```

**Test 2:**

```
$featured_posts = new WP_Query( $query_args );
$have_posts = $featured_posts->have_posts();
while ($have_posts) {
    $featured_posts->the_post();
    the_title(); echo '<br>';           
    $have_posts = $featured_posts->have_posts();
}
echo 'End: "' . $have_posts . '"'; // false -> I think false is right.              
echo 'End: "' . $featured_posts->have_posts() . '"'; // but still TRUE, WHY?
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at [`have_posts()` in source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/query.php#L3139), we can see why this happens:

```
function have_posts() {
    if ( $this->current_post + 1 < $this->post_count ) {
        return true;
    } elseif ( $this->current_post + 1 == $this->post_count && $this->post_count > 0 ) {
        do_action_ref_array('loop_end', array(&$this));
        // Do some cleaning up after the loop
        $this->rewind_posts();
    }

    $this->in_the_loop = false;
    return false;
}
```

When it reaches the end of the loop, it calls `rewind_posts`, which resets `current_post` back to `-1`, so the next call to `have_posts` will return true again.

```
function rewind_posts() {
    $this->current_post = -1;
    if ( $this->post_count > 0 ) {
        $this->post = $this->posts[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i have to change my algorithm a bit because of this.